# Silverlight - Parent of an element

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Now I have a question a little more complicated.

How do I get the parent element of an object.

For example:

```
<Viewbox>
<TextBlock Name="txtblock1" />
</Viewbox>
```

How do i get, via code (c#), the parent element of "txtblock1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property. The parent is returned as an `Object` so you'll need to cast it to be able to call `Viewbox`'s methods.

For example:

```
var vbox = txtblock1.Parent as Viewbox;
if( vbox != null ) {
  // do something with vbox
}
```

Comment: Just side note: it double checks if parent is Viewbox